# GZIP python3 AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'compress'

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-ec2

```
pipe.setnx(prefix+item[0], gzip.compress(bytes(item[1], 'utf-8')))
```

I'm trying to compress a file using the gzip python lib on an EC2 instance. I assume that gzip is part of the standard library. However, I get the following error

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'compress'
```

Comment: Do you have file `gzip.py` in your current directory? If so, rename it to something else and delete the directory \_\_pycache\_\_ before restarting the interpreter. You may also check `gzip.__spec__.origin`. make sure the modules comes from the standard distro.

Comment: I don't have any gzip.py files in my directory. This is running on an EC2 instance, so is it possible the AMI has included some file I can't see?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that someone else had added a library called gzip. So, it was defaulting to that one and the not standard library. I ended up using zlib instead.