# How to compress Json before uploading to Google Storage

Tags: python, json, google-cloud-storage

I'm using the following code (Python 2.7) to upload into Google Storage:

```
import datalab.storage as storage
storage.Bucket('MyBucket').item(path_raw).write_to(json.dumps(data), 'application/json')
```

This works great.  However I want to upload the file with compression so it will take less space. the `json.dumps()` has no option for compression and using something like:

```
with gzip.GzipFile('filename.json', 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write(json.dumps(data, outfile, sort_keys=True))
```

Doesn't solve my issue because it requires to save the file locally and then uploading it while my code create the file directly on Google Storage.

how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You are likely looking for [gzip.compress](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/gzip.html#gzip.compress) then. So you could then just put this here into your database:

```
gzip.compress(bytes(json.dumps(data), encoding="utf-8"))
```

(This only works on Python3.)

Comment: It gives AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'compress' I'm using Python 2.7 if that is related

Comment: Did you `import gzip`? What version of Python are you using?

Comment: 2.7.12 , yes I did import gzip

Comment: This function does not exist in Python2.7… it may be reasonable to migrate to Python3 by now. Python 2 has only 16 months left, so it's not going to stay forever anyway.

Comment: I'm aware of that but i can not migrate now.. I am sure that this issue has solutions other than migration

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51216128/gzip-python3-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-compress could this be similar? How do I try zlib

Comment: changed to zlib gives: TypeError: str() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)

Comment: Well, Python2 does not have a distinction between str and bytes yet. So I'd guess you can leave out the whole bytes conversion including the encoding. So only `gzip.compress(json.dumps(data))`…

Comment: This doesn't work either Unicode unequal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  if data != '':

Comment: I'm wondering why if I create a Pandas dataframe I can compress it without any problem. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html  see the argument for compression. This works on Python 2.7 how they managed that? Is my only solution is to create unnecessary object of dataframe just for compression?

Answer (score 1):

You can write to a buffer in memory instead of a file on disk:

```
from io import BytesIO
import gzip
stream = BytesIO()
with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=stream, mode='w') as gz:
    gz.write("some string")

# Reset stream
stream.seek(0)
print(stream.read())
```

If you can get away with directly using `zlib`, you may also use:

```
import zlib
zlib.compress(data)
```

Comment: zlib gives error: Unicode unequal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  if data != '':

Comment: That doesn't happen in my Python 2 console with just zlib. Are you sure that your storage bucket accepts arbitrary byte arrays that may not be valid UTF-8?

Comment: it accept: storage.Bucket('MyBucket').item(path_raw).write_to(json.dumps(data), 'application/json')   it doesn't accept storage.Bucket('MyBucket').item(path_raw).write_to(zlib.compress(json.dumps(data)), 'application/json')  - and the storage support compressed files so the problem isn't in the storage

Comment: Content type `application/json` is not valid for zlib-compressed data.

Comment: You could try `application/zlib`